# Python 2.7 pip or easy install won't work and will always time out, tried all stack overflow answers

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Windows 7

pip and easy_install always time out, I don't want to use manual zip downloads or .whl files as it messes up the versions.

This is what I am getting

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0364BD10>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests/
```

I need to know why it times out, as ping google.com works, I can access the PYPI site from the browser, it always returns success when I ping it from CMD.

Have tried all stack overflow answers, but none of them work.
I don't have any proxies on my machine.

```
pip install requests
pip install cx_Oracle
```

Expected is installation should be successful
But actual is timed out

Comment: have you tried doing it as Admin?

Comment: Do you mean launching cmd as admin?

Comment: exactly that :)

Comment: Didn't work :(.

Comment: What Python version?

Comment: 2.7 version python